# Android Accelerometer Issue

Tags: android, accelerometer

My game uses the accelerometer, everything works fine but I noticed there is going to be a slight issue with some phones. The game forces the orientation to be landscape however some phones have a default screen orientation of landscape...

Right now I was always assuming the user was going to have to tilt their phone to see the game correctly, this would mean the accelerometer reading for the X axis would move the player in the Y and the Y reading would move the player in the X. With the phones that have a default landscape screen the X will correspond to the X in game and the Y for the Y in game (as they wont need to tilt their phones.)

My question is how do I handle this? I can adapt the code to invert the X and Y directions based on the phones orientation, so how would I get the current orientation of the phone programmatically? If there is a better way that would be great

Hope that makes sense

EDIT:

Actually would it be safe to assume that if the devices length is greater than its height the screen would be defaulted to landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html:

> public int getRotation ()
>
> Returns the rotation of the screen from its "natural" orientation. The
>   returned value may be Surface.ROTATION_0 (no rotation),
>   Surface.ROTATION_90, Surface.ROTATION_180, or Surface.ROTATION_270.
>   For example, if a device has a naturally tall screen, and the user has
>   turned it on its side to go into a landscape orientation, the value
>   returned here may be either Surface.ROTATION_90 or
>   Surface.ROTATION_270 depending on the direction it was turned. The
>   angle is the rotation of the drawn graphics on the screen, which is
>   the opposite direction of the physical rotation of the device. For
>   example, if the device is rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise, to
>   compensate rendering will be rotated by 90 degrees clockwise and thus
>   the returned value here will be Surface.ROTATION_90.

You'll have to experiment with the devices to make sure android knows the "natural" orientation correctly. If so, then just check for ROTATION_90 (or ROTATION_270) to see if the device is on it's side or not. If so, then switch x and y axis.

Comment: I did try that but it always returns 0 no matter what way the phone is?

Comment: Does the "rotation" value depend of the rotation the screen is currently on or the rotation that my app is forcing upon it? It seems when I rotate the phone this value doesnt change but it is different from a "naturally" landscape phone compaired to a portrait one

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution provided by NVidia to deal nicely with the device default orientation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14313663/1489493