# Why does the Accelerometer coordinates change?

Tags: android

I get the accelerometer readings from the code segment below,

```
public AccelerometerHandler(Context context) {
    SensorManager manager = (SensorManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if (manager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size() != 0) {
        Sensor accelerometer = manager.getSensorList(
                Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        manager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    accelX = event.values[0];
    accelY = event.values[1];
    accelZ = event.values[2];
}

public float getAccelX() {
    return accelX;
}

public float getAccelY() {
    return accelY;
}

public float getAccelZ() {
    return accelZ;
}
```

When I try my application on a tablet device the X and Y accelerometer readings get swapped. How do I detect if the device is a tab and how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are they swapped, or rotated? Doesn't it depend on your definition of X, Y and Z? Maybe some devices think of themselves as "primarily portrait" and others "primarily landscape"? Not sure it is as simple as "phone vs tablet".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Orientation from Android Accelerometer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877780/orientation-from-android-accelerometer)

Comment: You can find an explanation at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html

Answer (score 0):

To check weather a device is Phone or tablet you can use following method,

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) 
{
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

[Source](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/compatability-manager-utility-class.html)